# Transfer data from one JS file to Another without

Tags: javascript, mobile, local-storage, data-transfer, session-storage

I'm just experimenting with stuff.

I want to know how I can transfer data from one JS file to another without linking the two files i.e using the script tag on the same HTML file.

So, when I click a button on one HTML file ('file1.html'), it does something to another HTML file (file2.html).

I have used 'localStorage.set/getItem' which did what I wanted. However, when I put my files online, and try open 'file1.html' on the browser of my mobile phone, the 'file2.html' which is open on my pc, does not seem to update when I click the button on my mobile phone.

I'm sure 'localStorage' will not fulfill my require unless anyone can show me otherwise. Is there any way I could still update 'file2.html' which is on pc, with the button click of 'file1.html' which is on my mobile?

*It works when both files are open on pc using localStorage.

Thank you.

Comment: *localStorage* stores data *locally* and therefore you won't be able to get data from your mobile to your pc with this method.

Comment: You will have to store the data on a server, and also depends on whether you want the client to have the data they create only visible to their pc and mobile, or not i.e. visible to all who visit that page online as in your question.

Comment: ok, Thank you, much appreciated.